# Assembly Program Compilation and Label Reference Problem

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm, qemu

so I'm trying to code a "Operating System" and Im using ASM for the code. I'm trying to read a user input here, and if the input is "test" it prints "spr".

Here's the code:

```
bits 16
org 0x7C00

section .bss
    inp_buf resb 256
    inp_len resb 1

section .data
    prompt db 'Enter text: $'
    compare_string db 'test', 0
    transform_string db 'spr', 0

section .text

global _start

_start:
    ; Set up the video mode (text mode)
    mov ah, 0x00
    mov al, 0x03
    int 0x10

    ; Print a prompt
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov bh, 0x00
    mov bl, 0x07
    mov si, prompt
    call print_string

    ; Read user input
    mov ah, 0
    int 0x16
    mov si, buffer
    mov cx, 255

.read_loop:
    mov ah, 0
    int 0x16
    cmp al, 0x0D
    je .done
    mov ah, 0x0E
    int 0x10
    stosb
    jmp .read_loop

.done:
    ; Check for "test" and print "spr" if found
    mov si, buffer
    call check_and_transform
    jnz .print_transformed
    ; If not "test," print the entered text
    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov si, buffer
    call print_string

    ; Infinite loop
    jmp $

print_string:
    .print_loop:
        lodsb
        cmp al, 0
        je .done
        int 0x10
        jmp .print_loop
    .done:
        ret

check_and_transform:
    pusha
    mov cx, 4
    mov di, buffer
    mov si, compare_string
.loop:
    lodsb
    cmp al, [si]
    jne .not_match
    loop .loop
    mov cx, 3
    mov si, transform_string
    rep movsb
    mov byte [di], 0
    popa
    ret
.not_match:
    popa
    ret

section .bss
    buffer resb 256
```

Expectations:
Succesfully compiled by NASM and if ran by QEMU|Reads user input and if user input = "test" then prints "spr"

Result:
While compiling:
boot.asm:50: error: symbol `_start.print_transformed' not defined

Comment: `jnz .print_transformed`. I don't see this label in Your code. Maybe this line shouldn't be there, after `call`.

Comment: This looks strange to me: `.loop: lodsb; cmp al, [si]`. `lodsb` is essentially the same as `mov al, [si]; inc si`, so this is comparing an element in the string with the next one - was that the intention?